# Best of 5 games

Tags: probability, statistics

The Cowboys are playing a best of five game series against the Patriots. Let X denote the total number of games played in the series. Assume that the Cowboys win 59% of their games against the Patriots and dthat the probability of winning a game is independent of other games.

a) Calculate the mean and standard deviation for X.
b) Calculate the conditional mean and standard deviation for X given that the patriots win the 1st game.

So I found there are a total of 14 games that can be played. I don't know how to relate the probability to the questions though. I'm not sure if that is extra information but I still obtain a wrong answer. For b) I know there can only be 13 games possible but again I'm not sure how to relate the probabilites help?

Comment: why 14 games? best of five should at most have 9 games in total.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate 1)the chance that Cowboys win the series at 4:0? 2) the chance that Cowboys win the series at 4:1

Comment: because you can WWW, LLL WWLLW WWLW WLLWW WWLLL WLLL WLWW WLWLL LWWW LLWWW LLWL LLWWL LWLL which comes out to about 14 possible games in a best of 5

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstand the meaning of "best of five.". So given that each win has a chance of $59\%$. Do you know what is the probability of WWW?

Comment: yes it is $(0.59)^3$ but I somewhat see how to relate the probabilities and there are actually 18 possible games. I missed 4

Comment: one more step ahead. what is probability of WWLW? is it the same as WLWW and LWWW?

Comment: b.t.w I think there are a total of 20 possibilites of the series..

Comment: Calculate $\Pr(X=k)$. The probability that $X=3$ is $(0.58)^2+(0.41)^2$. For the probability that $X=4$, two cases, Cowboys win in $4$ and Pats win in $4$. To win in $4$, Cowboys must lose one of the first $3$ games ($3$ choices) and win the fourth. Probability is $(3)(0.59)^2(0.41)(0.59)$. Similar expression for Pats win in $4$, add. For $5$, could do something similar, but easier to use $1-\Pr(X=3)-\Pr(X=4)$. Now that you have the distribution, you can find the mean and variance. And they don't play best of five series in football.

Comment: isn't ir $0.59^3 $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cowboys wins at 3:0   WWW  $p(3:0)=(0.59)^3$
2. Cowboys wins at 3:1
    The first 3 games gives 2:1 (no matter what is the order), and the Cowboys wins the fourth.
    There are $C_3^1=3$ possible ways that first three games gives 2:1 (WWL, WLW, LWW) with the same probability $(0.59)^2*0.41$. So $p(3:1)=3*(0.59)^2*0.41*0.59$
3. Cowboys wins at 3:2

   The first 4 games gives 2:2, and the Cowboys wins the fifth.
    There are $C_4^2=6$ possible ways that first four games gives 2:2 (WWLL, WLWL, WLLW, LWWL, LWLW, LLWW) with the same probability $(0.59)^2*(0.41)^2$. So $p(3:2)=6*(0.59)^2*(0.41)^2*0.59$

Similarly you can calculate $p(2:3)$, $p(1:3)$, $p(0:3)$
And the mean of $X$ is, by definition
$$
\bar{X}=3*[p(3:0)+p(0:3)]+4*[p(3:1)+p(1:3)]+5*[p(3:2)+p(2:3)]
$$
The variance is, by definition
$$
\text{Var}(X)=[p(3:0)+p(0:3)](3-\bar{X})^2 + [p(3:1)+p(1:3)](4-\bar{X})^2+ [p(3:2)+p(2:3)](5-\bar{X})^2
$$

Comment: but you are leaving out the possibility of them losing no?

Comment: You can calculate their chance of losing by calculating $p(0:3)$, $p(1:3)$ and $p(2:3)$. very similar to what I did for the cases they win the series.

Comment: the part that is confusing me is part A. I get the answer for part b. I don't understand if I need to account for probability in a because they are only talking about the total number of games